# could not upload image in windows server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

here is my code.can you guys tell me where i wrong..i could see the correct image path with image name and it is not uploading..but no response..

```
if(isset($_FILES['image_file']))
{
    $max_size = 500;  $destination_folder='D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\websitename(example.com)\httpdocs\app\folder';
    $watermark_png_file = 'watermark.png';
    $image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size'];
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image_file']['type'];
    switch(strtolower($image_type)){
            case 'image/png': 
                $image_resource =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $image_resource =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                $image_resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
                break;
            default:
                $image_resource = false;
        }
    if($image_resource){
        //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($image_temp);
        //Construct a proportional size of new image
        $image_scale        = min($max_size / $img_width, $max_size / $img_height); 
        $new_image_width    = ceil($image_scale * $img_width);
        $new_image_height   = ceil($image_scale * $img_height);
        $new_canvas         = imagecreatetruecolor($new_image_width , $new_image_height);
        if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $image_resource , 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_image_width, $new_image_height, $img_width, $img_height))
        {
            if(!is_dir($destination_folder)){ 
                mkdir($destination_folder);//create dir if it doesn't exist
            }
            $watermark_left = ($new_image_width)-(300/2); //watermark left
            $watermark_bottom = ($new_image_height)-(300/2); //watermark bottom
       $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_png_file); //watermark image
            imagecopy($new_canvas, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, 75, 75); //merge image
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_folder.'/'.$image_name , 90);
            imagedestroy($new_canvas); 
            imagedestroy($image_resource);
            die();
        }}}
```

please help me to upload.IS there any settings or anything,..

Comment: may be your form need these attributes` method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: <form name="jes" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php?f=imageupload">..sorry..but thanks for the reply..